# How do I configure a Python interpreter in IntelliJ IDEA with the PyCharm plugin?

Tags: python, intellij-idea

There is a tutorial in the IDEA docs on how to add a Python interpreter in PyCharm, which involves accessing the "Project Interpreter" page. Even after installing the Python plugin, I don't see that setting anywhere.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: it should be under file > settings > project interpreter

Comment: @JoranBeasley, There is no such setting as of IDEA 14

Answer (score 166):

With the Python plugin installed:

1. Navigate to File > Project Structure.
2. Under the Project menu for Project SDK, select "New" and
3. Select "Python SDK", then select "Local".

Provided you have a Python SDK installed, the flow should be natural from there - navigate to the location your Python installation lives.

Comment: Is there a way to have two intepreters, one for python and one for java *at the same time*?  Meaning I dont have to switch back and forth.

Comment: @DavidWilliams Yes, you should create Java project with Python *facet* for the same module. You can do that either in new project wizard (select Python under "Additional Libraries and Frameworks" on the first page) or in project structure later (*File | Project Structure |  Facets*).

Comment: Even though I have one this before it requires research to figure out how to repeat the process.Also the process has been changing with most new IJ releases.

Comment: For the latest versions of Jetbrains IDEs "Project structure" is inside the settings menu `ctrl + alt + S`

Answer (score 24):

I was getting the error (IntelliJ on Ubuntu 18.04) while python SDK was configured.

To fix that, I had to do this:

1. `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Modules`
2. Click on the `Dependencies` tab, and click on `+` and select the python SDK

   [image]
3. Click on `Apply`

After that, the warning went away and autocompletion also started working properly

Answer (score 12):

So here is a simple project, where I have used `Selenium` and added that using external path

[image: Error]

Now you need to open `Project Structure` and go to `SDK` Section

[image: Project Structure]

Now Select your project's virtual environment. In the `Classpath` tab add the `PYTHONPATH` by clicking `+` button

[image: Add SDK]

and now the modules will be recognized

[image: Module recognized]

Comment: Thanks Tarun. It seems I was not using the newly installed Python SDK with PySpark in IntelliJ IDE. And thanks for pointing out the site-packages (and PythonPath classpath)

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. Open Setting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>)
2. Click on plugins
3. Find Browse Repositories and click
4. Search for "python"
5. Select Python SDK or pycharm
6. Restart the IDE
7. Go to project structure
8. Select the python SDK in projects or create a new project with python SDK.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple modules in your project, with different languages, you can set the interpreter in the following way:

- `File -> Project Structure...`
- Select `Modules` in the list on the left
- Select the Python module in the list of modules
- On the right-hand side, either choose an existing Python SDK from the dropdown list, or click on the `New...` button to create either a virtualenv, or create a new Python SDK from a Python installation on your system.