# python profiler not available in Intellij 15.0.2

Tags: python, intellij-idea

My intellij version is 15.0.2. But in the run context menu, there is no option regarding profiling a piece of code. 
Anyone knows what goes wrong?

Comment: Are you using CE or Ultimate?

Comment: Perhaps you should be using PyCharm? I'm not aware of Python support in IntelliJ.

Comment: yes, without pycharm, one could not use python in intellij at all

Comment: @MattBall:  [It exists.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769117/how-do-i-configure-a-python-interpreter-in-intellij-idea-with-the-pycharm-plugin/24769264#24769264)  I assure you of that.

Comment: are you talking about the python profiler？

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Python profiler does not show up in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, if the UML plugin is not enabled. At least this worked for me. I had the same issue and asked JetBrains directly.

Comment: The same happened to me in PyCharm. I disabled the UML plugin and the "Run with profiler" action disappeared from the toolbar and the menu. After re-enabling the plugin, the problem was fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Python profiling is only available in PyCharm Professional and in the version of the Python plugin for IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. It's not available in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.

Comment: For me at least, Profile command appeared only after recreating IDEA settings. I had Python plugin already earlier, but there was no Profiling options.

Comment: I have IntelliJ Ultimate and Python plugin (description text says: The feature set of the plugin corresponds to PyCharm IDE Professional Edition). But still no Profile run button.